# Find the query for comparing fiscal quarter results with the previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, adventureworks

Using MS SQL Server 2014 and AdventureWorks2012 DB.

Currently trying to work out the correct query to reach a result which displays total sales value for each sales person for fiscal quarters with on the same row, a comparison to the fiscal quarter of the previous year. The columns I should have in the result are;

- LastName
- SalesPersonID
- Fiscal year
- Fiscal quarter
- Fiscal quarter sales
- Sales during the same fiscal quarter of the previous fiscal year
- Change in revenue between the two periods
- Percent change in revenue between the two periods

My query below does not include the final 2 columns as I am unsure how to get them? However the query without them also seems incorrect as it is not getting the desired result.

I have tried to run this code without having `soh.OrderDate` in the `GROUP BY` which was something I did previously for another related query however this returns the following error hence I have included it back in the `GROUP BY`;

> Column 'Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```sql
SELECT pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID,
    CASE
      WHEN soh.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
        THEN '2013'
    END AS FY,
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '1'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '2'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '3'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4'
    END AS FQ,
    CASE 
      WHEN soh.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
        THEN 
          SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN soh.SubTotal
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN soh.SubTotal
            WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN soh.SubTotal
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN soh.SubTotal
          END)
    END AS FQSales, 
    CASE 
      WHEN soh.OrderDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30' 
        THEN 
          SUM(CASE
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN soh.SubTotal
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN soh.SubTotal
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN soh.SubTotal
        WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN soh.SubTotal
          END)
    END AS SalesSameLastFQ
FROM Sales.SalesPerson sp
INNER JOIN Person.Person pp 
    ON sp.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh 
    ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
GROUP BY pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID, soh.OrderDate;
```

Current result, getting different permutations for each Sales Person however I expect to have 4 results for each sales person, 1 for each FQ.

```
LastName     SalesPersonID     FY      FQ   FQSales  SalesSameLastYr
------------------------------------------------------------------
Alberts          283          NULL     1   NULL      NULL
Alberts          283          NULL     1    NULL     32344.342
Alberts          283          NULL     3   NULL      NULL
Alberts          283          2013     2   342432      NULL
Alberts          283          NULL     4    NULL     32344.342
Alberts          283          NULL     3   NULL      NULL
Alberts          283          NULL     4    NULL     32344.342
Alberts          283          2013     2   436346      NULL
```

Desired result:

```
LastName  SalesPersID   FY   FQ FQSales SalesSameLastYr Change Change%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Alberts      283       2013   1  2000     1900           100      5
Alberts      283       2013   2  2200     2000           200      10
Alberts      283       2013   3  2000     2100          -100     -5
Alberts      283       2013   4  3000     2850           150      5
Mathews      291       2013   1  2000     1900           100      5
Mathews      291       2013   2  2200     2000           200      10
Mathews      291       2013   3  2000     2100          -100     -5
Mathews      291       2013   4  3000     2850           150      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should separate the data in two tables one for each year, culculating the FY and FQ for each one.:

```
SELECT pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID,'2013' as FY,
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '1'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '2'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '3'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4'
    END AS FQ,
    soh.SubTotal
into #tmpCurrentYear
FROM Sales.SalesPerson sp
INNER JOIN Person.Person pp ON sp.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
where soh.OrderDate between '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30'

SELECT pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID,'2012' as FY,
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '1'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '2'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '3'
      WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4'
    END AS FQ,
    soh.SubTotal
into #tmpLastYear
FROM Sales.SalesPerson sp
INNER JOIN Person.Person pp ON sp.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
where soh.OrderDate between '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30'
```

And then join them and do the group by without the orderDate or it will create one row for each date:

```
select t.LastName, t.SalesPersonID,t.FY,t.FQ, sum(t.SubTotal) as FQSales,         
sum(ly.SubTotal) as SalesSameLastFQ, sum(t.SubTotal)-sum(ly.SubTotal) as Change, 
      (sum(t.SubTotal)-sum(ly.SubTotal))/(sum(t.SubTotal)) as ChangePercentage
from #tmpCurrentYear as t
    INNER JOIN  #tmpLastYear as ly ON t.LastName = ly.LastName and t.BusinessEntityID = ly.BusinessEntityID and t.FQ = ly.FQ
group by t.LastName, t.SalesPersonID,t.FY,t.FQ
```

Comment: Perfect thank you i've never come across using temp tables from my learning so will be learning about that today. With this I just needed to change t.BusinessEntityID = ly.BusinessEntityID to t.SalesPersonID = ly.SalesPersonID on the very last join for it to execute without error.

Comment: @Nathan . . . Temporary table -- or even subqueries or CTEs -- are unnecessary for this this.  Only JOINs and aggregation are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID,
       v.FY, v.FQ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FY = 2012 THEN soh.SubTotal END) as FY_prev,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FY = 2013 THEN soh.SubTotal END) as FY_curr,
       ( SUM(CASE WHEN FY = 2013 THEN soh.SubTotal END) /
         SUM(CASE WHEN FY = 2012 THEN soh.SubTotal END)
       ) - 1 as percent
FROM Sales.SalesPerson sp INNER JOIN
     Person.Person pp
     ON sp.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID INNER JOIN
     Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
     ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ((CASE WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '1'
                    WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '2'
                    WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '3'
                    WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4'
               END),
              (CASE WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) < 7 THEN YEAR(soh.OrderDate)
                    ELSE YEAR(soh.OrderDate) + 1
               END)
              )
     ) v(FQ, FY)
WHERE FY IN (2013, 2012)
GROUP BY pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID, v.FY, v.FQ;
```

This uses `CROSS APPLY` to create values.  This can also be accomplished with CTEs or subqueries.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I still get an error with this syntax. `Column v.FY is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` Also, please can you explain the `v.` how does that work as can't see `v` as an alias anywhere. Thank you